# How many irreducible representations can a group of order $12$ have?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

We can decompose $12 = 12 \times 1$, $12 = 1+1+1+1+4+4$, $12=1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+4$. Those are the only possibilies, but not enough for me to count all possibilities. One way to do this is to list all groups of order $12$, then calculate for each of them. Is there a better strategy?

Comment: Do a lookup in [Database of group character tables](http://u.math.biu.ac.il/~mschaps/DATA/database.html) derived from [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/index.html) which you can use directly if you know how to give the right commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$[G:G']$ is the number of degree $1$ irreducible representation. So your last case is impossible. There are only $5$ groups of order $12$, two of which is abelian (and hence $12 = 12\times 1$). The three non-ablian groups are $D_{12},A_4$ and $T$ (up to isomorphism). You can try to find the explicit representations by the given degrees. Don't forget $12 = 3\times 1+9$.